# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a rails app using ERB as my templating and keep getting this error: `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`.

My **event.html.erb** looks like:

```
        <% @event.each do |event| %>
            <a href="/registrations/new?level_id=1" class="btn"><%= event.date.strftime("%B %d %Y") %></a>
            <br /><br />
        <% end %>
```

My **register_controller.rb** looks like this:

```
class RegisterController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @event = Event.all
    end 
end

def event
    @event = Event.find_by id: params["id"]
end
```

My **event.rb** model:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

My route is this: `get 'register/event/:id' => 'register#event'`

When I go to /register/event/1/ I receive the error message `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: unless you had monkey patched `find_by`, would not expect `each` available on @event if record found

Comment: also would have look at `params['id']`, maybe `params[:id]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to iterate on a single object. Your `event.html.erb` file should simply look like:

```
   <a href="/registrations/new?level_id=1" class="btn">
     <%= @event.date.strftime("%B %d %Y") %>
   </a>
```

Also, it looks like that there is no object in the DB with your specified `params[:id]`

Also your controller, should look like this:

```
class RegisterController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @event = Event.all
    end 

    def event
       @event = Event.find_by id: params[:id]
    end
end
```

Comment: it then complains on`undefined method 'date' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: @TreyCopeland you need to ensure that the record exists with the specified `params["id"]`

Comment: @aliibrahim thanks for following up. i have edited to show mysql structure. see my original post, it contains id & date.

Comment: @TreyCopeland in your controller, can you change `@event = Event.find_by id: params["id"]` to `@event = Event.find_by id: params[:id]`

Comment: same issue, complaining about date

Comment: Can you paste your `event.rb` file as well?

Comment: @TreyCopeland i'm guessing no record was found in your `event` method and then where you went to call date on a nil object in the view an error was raised

Comment: @TreyCopeland i have updated my answer with what should go inside your controller. Looks like you were ending controller before your `def event` was defined inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're asking it to iterate over a single instance.

could go with:

```
<a href="/registrations/new?level_id=1" class="btn">
  <%= @event.date.strftime("%B %d %Y") if @event %>
</a>
<br /><br />
```

in `event.html.erb`

Comment: trey, see where I have the `if @event`?